# Infinite loop when using array map

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop

Since I added

```
const dataList = dataSet.map(element => {
  return <div>{element}</div>;
});
```

It has gone into an infinite loop but this line is also necessary for my program to display the notes so what can I do?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

function Notes() {
  //This is just a string because we are sending just one
  //might have to make it an array at some point
  const [notes, setNote] = useState(String);

  var dataArr = [];

  const [dataSet, setDataSet] = useState([]);

  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Use Effect Notes.js');

    axios
      .post('/api/user/notes')
      .then(res => {
        dataArr = res.data[0].notes;
        //console.log(dataArr) ;
        console.log(dataArr);
        setDataSet(res.data[0].notes);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('it didnt work' + err);
      });

    console.log('The array that i got ');
  });

  const dataList = dataSet.map(element => {
    return <div>{element}</div>;
  });

  /*const taskList = task.map((object , index)=>{
        return <div className='row justify-content-center'>

            <h2>{object}</h2>

        </div>
    });*/

  function noteDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var newNote = {
      notes: notes,
    };

    console.log('note down ' + newNote);
    axios
      .post('/api/user/notes/add', newNote)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  function ffswork() {
    console.log('ffswork');
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1> Notes </h1>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={noteDown}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Note"
          className="form-control"
          value={notes}
          onChange={e => {
            setNote(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="AddNote" className="btn btn-primary" />
      </form>
      <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={ffswork}>
        getData
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Notes;
```

[image: console log of infinite loop]

Comment: Why is `dataList` declared twice? `dataList` is not even consumed in your code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to pass the array in the second argument from `useEffect`.

```
  useEffect(() =>{
        console.log("Use Effect Notes.js");

        axios.post('/api/user/notes' ).then(res=>{
            dataArr = res.data[0].notes ; 
            //console.log(dataArr) ;
            console.log(dataArr); 
            setDataSet(res.data[0].notes); 
           
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log('it didnt work' + err); 
        }); 


        console.log("The array that i got ");

    }, []) // at this line
```

> You can tell React to skip applying an effect if certain values
> haven’t changed between re-renders.

So, if you want to make the request to get your data just once just after render, you just need to pass an empty array in the second argument of `useEffect`.

Read More [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).